# Reselecting a tab on bottom navigation clearing stack while using navigation component

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation, android-bottomnav

Have 4 fragments A,B,C,D in my bottom navigation setup with navigation component with A fragment as home destination , when I  navigate from A to another fragment say fragment E with findNavController().navigate(id)  then switched to another tab in bottom navigation say Fragment D as current fragment if pressed back its  taking me back to Fragment A or home missing the pushed fragment E .

Any way to handle this?

Comment: If you select the tab for fragment A, does E still appear?

Comment: @ianhanniballake  yes if i select tab for A , E fragment appears but if i press back button its taking me directly back to Fragment A